# Calculate a Basis of the subspaces U and V

Tags: linear-algebra

$V=\{\big( 1,0,2 \big),\big( -2,0,5 \big)\} $
$U=\{\big(-1,0,3 \big)\} $

Calculate a basis of the subspaces $U+V$.

My approach is to show that the vectors are linearly independent and then I have my basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U$ and $V$ are not vector spaces, so I assume you're asking about $span(U)+span(V)$. This will simply be $span(U \cup V) = span(\{(1,0,2),(-2,0,5),(-1,0,3)\})$. Since $$(-2,0,5)=\frac{9}{5}(-1,0,3)-\frac{1}{5}(1,0,2),$$ this set is linearly dependent and removing $(-2,0,5)$ leaves the span unchanged. The remaining set $\{(1,0,2),(-1,0,3)\}$ is a basis for $span(U)+span(V)$ because it is linearly independent.